# Use user-defined function in CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm trying to create the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredient.Ingredient 
(
    GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL,
    Name NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

but I've come to realize that the max size of a `NVARCHAR UNIQUE` column is 450 (at least in the current version of SQL Server). In order to not use magic literals I've created a user-defined function that returns the current max size of a `NVARCHAR UNIQUE` column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Max NVARCHAR Index Size]()
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
    RETURN(450)
END
```

This function runs correctly when called as

```
SELECT dbo.[Max NVARCHAR Index Size]()
```

I was hoping to use this function in a `CREATE TABLE` statement, but it errors as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredient.Ingredient 
(
    GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL,
    Name NVARCHAR(dbo.[Max NVARCHAR Index Size]()) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> Incorrect syntax near '('

To try and circumvent this I made a variable with the value of the function, and then using the variable, but that didn't work either.

```
DECLARE
    @NVARCHARIndexSize INTEGER = dbo.[MAX NVARCHAR Index Size]()

CREATE TABLE Ingredient.Ingredient 
(
    GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL,
    Name NVARCHAR(@NVARCHARIndexSize) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
> Incorrect syntax near '@NVARCHARIndexSize'

where line 13 is `Name NVARCHAR(@NVARCHARIndexSize) NOT NULL UNIQUE`.

Is there a way to use variables/functions instead of literals in a `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way you can do what you are trying to do is with dynamic SQL. You cannot define a `nvarchar` using a parameter as the size.

Answer (score 3):

DDL can't be parameterized.  You'd have to use dynamic SQL for that.  eg

```
DECLARE
@NVARCHARIndexSize INTEGER = dbo.[MAX NVARCHAR Index Size]()

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('
CREATE TABLE Ingredient.Ingredient 
(
    GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL,
    Name NVARCHAR(',@NVARCHARIndexSize,') NOT NULL UNIQUE
)'
)

exec (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if this was an intended design decision or a side-effect of SQL being a DDL?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom type in SQL Server with following syntax

```
CREATE TYPE MyCustomType  
FROM NVARCHAR(420);
```

And later on can use the custom type while creating tables

```
CREATE TABLE Ingredient 
(
    GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL ROWGUIDCOL,
    [Name] MyCustomType NOT NULL UNIQUE
)
```

Comment: Don't you have to drop all instances of the custom type to be able to modify it in the future?

Comment: Does using a custom type require any considerations in the future? As in, is `MyCustomType` considered identical to `NVARCHAR(420)` in all situations? Just making sure I don't screw myself in the future by using a custom type.

Comment: I think you screw yourself because you can't alter it.

Comment: Using a custom type and using temp tables can lead to issues, as custom type will not be present in the temp table. Also as @DaleK suggested, you cannot alter custom type

Comment: Given the specifics of this scenario and the intent to standardize, I'd say the immutability of the custom type is appropriate and not likely to be a problem. Inaccessibility from tempdb will probably come up at some point, so that's annoying, but still the elegance of the custom type wins out for me.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to SQL Server 2016, the maximum key length was 900 bytes. [MSDN Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#index-key-size)

> #### Index Key Size
>
> The maximum size for an index key is 900 bytes for a clustered index and 1,700 bytes for a nonclustered index. (Before
> SQL Database and SQL Server 2016 (13.x) the limit was always 900
> bytes.) Indexes on varchar columns that exceed the byte limit can be
> created if the existing data in the columns do not exceed the limit at
> the time the index is created; however, subsequent insert or update
> actions on the columns that cause the total size to be greater than
> the limit will fail. The index key of a clustered index cannot contain
> varchar columns that have existing data in the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA
> allocation unit. If a clustered index is created on a varchar column
> and the existing data is in the IN_ROW_DATA allocation unit,
> subsequent insert or update actions on the column that would push the
> data off-row will fail.
>
> Nonclustered indexes can include non-key columns in the leaf level of
> the index. These columns are not considered by the Database Engine
> when calculating the index key size

You can define a NVARCHAR(450) column with check constraint, to ensure that your data does not go beyond 450 characters. I would suggest you to use DATALENGTH to ensure that column length is <= 900.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #test(id int identity(1,1) not null, 
a NVARCHAR(500) CHECK (DATALENGTH(a) <= 900),
CONSTRAINT ak_a unique(a))


insert into #test
values('a') -- 1 row affected

insert into #test
values(REPLICATE('a',450)) -- 1 row affected

insert into #test
values(REPLICATE('a',451)) -- Error
```

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 12 The INSERT statement conflicted
> with the CHECK constraint "CK__#test__________a__AC6651A7". The
> conflict occurred in database "tempdb", table "#test", column 'a'.

In future, when you move to higher versions, you can increase length of NVARCHAR and CHECK constraint accordingly.

Comment: Is `CONSTRAINT ak_a unique(a)` as performant is typing the field as unique?

Comment: both are same only. when you type UNIQUE the unique constraint name will be system generated name. when you type the name yourself, your name will be chosen